# Comparison Based Sort Using Priority Queue - Bound On Queue Comparisons

Tags: algorithm, sorting, priority-queue

I need to show that you cannot have a compare-based PQ algorithm where both insert and deleteMax use less than lg(N)/3 + O(1) compare operations, where N is the current length of the queue.

I understand that it has to do with the the compare-based sorting bound Nlog(N), but cannot quite arrive at the required value.

Please help!

Comment: What does "faster than log(N)/3" actually mean? Do you mean fewer comparisons than log(N)/3?

Comment: Yes, N is the current length of the queue. I modified the question accordingly

Comment: I can't show specifically `log(n)/3 + 1`, but we know that a compare-based priority queue can't be faster than O(log n) for (*insert* + *delete-max*), because if it did then you could sort faster than O(n log n). Which is kind of like the algorithmic equivalent of exceeding the speed of light. By the way, where did you get the `log(n)/3 + 1`?

Comment: from the problem I am trying to solve :), also perplexed about it. I wonder if they mean lg2(10) ~ 3? I got O(log n) as well, but still cannot match the given formula

Answer (score 2):

This pretty much follows from the [standard analysis of the decision tree bound on comparison-based sorting](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960116.html).

There are *n!* permutations, which is the number of the leaves of the decision tree. The height of the tree is at least *log(n!) - O(1)*.

Conversely, if you could actually do the operations using the number of comparisons in the question, the height would be at most

*2 ∑<sub>i = 1</sub><sup>n</sup>[log(i) / 3 + O(1)]*

(where the multiplying 2 is because there are both inserts and delete-maxs).

However,

*2 ∑<sub>i = 1</sub><sup>n</sup>[log(i) / 3 + O(1)] = 2 / 3 log(n!) + Θ(n)*.

Clearly, by [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation),

*lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> [(2 / 3 log(n!) + Θ(n)) / (log(n!) - O(1)] = 2 / 3*.

This shows that, asymptotically, the height of the tree is not enough - it is about 2/3 of what is needed.

Comment: where did you get log(i)/3 + O(1) ?

Comment: @Alex It's what your question states as the assumption, but with a change of variable. At iteration *i*, there are *i* elements in the queue, so the number of comparisons is *log(i) / 3 + O(1)*.

Comment: This does not really matter for the argument, but how does sum of O(1) give Theta(n)? Should be O(n) instead.

Comment: @Henry I see your point. Under very weak assumptions widely used in this field (i.e., that all functions are strictly positive), *O(1)* often really means a constant, or *&Theta;(1)* (so adding it *n* times is *n* constants, or *&Theta;(n)*. But I agree with you that it could be done that way too. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I think log(I)/3 + O(1) is what you need to prove as a lower bound, not the assumption.

Comment: Is it as simple as to say that whether you keep your PQ order or not, to do a combination of insert and delMax, you need to go through comparing every element of the Q, hence you can only do it as fast as N log2 N + const? What do you think?

Comment: @vladz Regarding your first point: I don't think so. If you read the question + the last comment by the OP on it, I think it's clear the meaning is that this is the assumption, and it needs to be disproved.

Comment: @vladz Regarding your second point: not sure exactly what you mean by "you need to go through comparing every element of the Q". Specifically, comparison with what? If you mean that the new element needs to be compared to every one, then that's not quite correct.

Comment: Let's say you insert and immediately delete a new element that happened to be the largest in the queue. You need to go thought N comparisons no matter what is the structure of the queue.

Comment: @vladz How did you get that idea? That would be a very inefficient PQ implementation.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant that to do the combination of insert and delMax you need to search through the whole tree, which is log2 N + const

Comment: @vladz That sounds reasonable, but it needs proof. When you want to prove it for the iterated case, I think you end up with something like the decision tree model.